# Can someone help me with one of the pagination effect using javascript?

Tags: javascript

http://`jsfiddle.net`/mBH9W/2/

1. I want to show only 3 consecutive numbers in a row.(ex:1 2 3)
2. Click the "next" button, and it shows 4 5 6, then 7 8
3. Click the "prev" button, and it shows 4 5 6, then 1 2 3

Can someone help me to code in javascript?

THANKS A LOT!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Bootstrap Paginator](http://bootstrappaginator.org/)** plugin for this purpose. It can be configured to fit your needs.

Snippet:

```
 <div id="example"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var options = {
            currentPage: 3,
            totalPages: 10
        }

        $('#example').bootstrapPaginator(options);
    </script>
```